# Set up sorting on js

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I have this code, but it does not work correctly.

My problem is that these filters work as I need separately. Filtering should work on both filters. How to make them work together? How to fix it, what would they have worked together?

```js
let productBox = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
let selectCategory = document.querySelector('#select-category');
let selectPrice = document.querySelector('#select-price');

selectCategory.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
     let selectVal = evt.currentTarget.value;
     Array.prototype.forEach.call(productBox, prodItem => {
      if((selectVal !== 'all') && (prodItem.dataset.category !== selectVal)) {
       prodItem.style.display = 'none'
      } else {
       prodItem.style.display = 'block'
      }
     })
});

selectPrice.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
     let selectVal = evt.currentTarget.value;
     Array.prototype.forEach.call(productBox, prodItem => {
      if((selectVal === '0') || (+prodItem.dataset.price <= +selectVal)) {
       prodItem.style.display = 'block'
      } else {
       prodItem.style.display = 'none'
      }
     })
})
```

```css
.product {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<select id="select-category">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="dinner">Dinner</option>
    <option value="first meal">First meal</option>
    <option value="garnish">Garnish</option>
</select>

<select id="select-price">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="30">Up to 30 dollars</option>
    <option value="50">Up to 50 dollars</option>
    <option value="100">Up to 100 dollars</option>
</select>

<div data-category="dinner" data-price="30" class="product">Dinner</div>
<div data-category="first meal" data-price="50" class="product">First meal</div>
<div data-category="dinner" data-price="45" class="product">Dinner2</div>
<div data-category="first meal" data-price="55" class="product">First meal2</div>
<div data-category="garnish" data-price="100" class="product">Garnish</div>
<div data-category="garnish" data-price="120" class="product">Garnish2</div>
```

Comment: Have each of those loops add or remove a class that says whether each select would accept the category, and then use CSS to hide everything that doesn't satisfy both (i.e., doesn't have both classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS rules and classes that you add/remove to do what you want. That way the elements will "remember" the effects of the filters.

```js
let productBox = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
let selectCategory = document.querySelector('#select-category');
let selectPrice = document.querySelector('#select-price');

selectCategory.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
  let selectVal = evt.currentTarget.value;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(productBox, prodItem => {
    if ((selectVal === 'all') || (prodItem.dataset.category === selectVal)) {
      prodItem.classList.add("category-good");
    } else {
      prodItem.classList.remove("category-good");
    }
  })
});

selectPrice.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
  let selectVal = evt.currentTarget.value;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(productBox, prodItem => {
    if ((selectVal === 'all') || (+prodItem.dataset.price <= +selectVal)) {
      prodItem.classList.add("price-good");
    } else {
      prodItem.classList.remove("price-good")
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.product {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: .5rem;
  display: none;
}

.product.category-good.price-good {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select id="select-category">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="dinner">Dinner</option>
  <option value="first meal">First meal</option>
  <option value="garnish">Garnish</option>
</select>

<select id="select-price">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="30">Up to 30 dollars</option>
  <option value="50">Up to 50 dollars</option>
  <option value="100">Up to 100 dollars</option>
</select>

<div data-category="dinner" data-price="30" class="product category-good price-good">Dinner</div>
<div data-category="first meal" data-price="50" class="product category-good price-good">First meal</div>
<div data-category="dinner" data-price="45" class="product category-good price-good">Dinner2</div>
<div data-category="first meal" data-price="55" class="product category-good price-good">First meal2</div>
<div data-category="garnish" data-price="100" class="product category-good price-good">Garnish</div>
<div data-category="garnish" data-price="120" class="product category-good price-good">Garnish2</div>
```

It might be a little cleaner to set things up such that you trigger an event on each `<select>` at startup so that you don't have to explicitly add the initial "good" classes to the `<div>` elements, but it's not that ugly.